# How to handle a wp8 and a wp8.1 in the app store

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

A user recently reported a problem in regards to not being able to answer "quizzes" in some of the web pages I display in my app. The first thing that popped to mind was that it could be a bug with my app, a bug with the web browser control or some unreliable `CSS` & `Javascript` code provided in the web pages.

After investigating it some more i.e. tried it on my web browser on pc in mobile mode and tried it in the regular browser, I noticed that it worked as expected, so I thought it was fair to assume that it wasn't the web pages that were the problem. So it left my app or the web browser control as potential problem.

My app was originally created as a windows phone app for Windows Phone 8 so it would be compatible with both windows phone 8.0 and windows phone 8.1 but to my surprise, after taking a backup and then converting my app from 8.0 to 8.1 the problem got resolved which means that the bug must be coming from the web control itself rather than in my code.

I don't know how popular these questionaires/quizzes are but so far that seems to be the only thing that's affecting the app in regards to web pages, so what do I do?

Now, to my questions (sorry for the long history!):

1. Will a WP Silverlight 8.1 app work on both Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1? Sorry if it's a silly question but I've got to ask. If it will, please ignore the other questions.
2. Should I leave the app as a Windows Phone 8.0 app as it could be affecting a minority of users that want to answer questionnaires/quizzes?
3. Upgrade the app to Windows Phone 8.1? Not everyone is on 8.1 or 8.1 preview for developers, so this could be a problem??
4. Upload 2 different versions? Maybe specifically name them as app 8.0 and app 8.1? Feels odd, no? This would also entail maintaining 2 different versions which is a complete pain or is there a better way to handle this i.e. Linked file in the second project?? I haven't checked yet what's changed between the 2. All I know for now is that once I converted my project from 8.0 to 8.1, it worked.
5. Is there a way to upload both versions to the store as one app and will Windows Phone download the relevant version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer in Windows Phone 8.1 is newer, this is why it works better.

1) No.

2) No.

3) Yes.

4) Yes. You can link files from the one project to another (use `add as link` feature in Visual Studio).

5) Yes. Windows Phone store can handle 7.5, 8 and 8.1 version very well.

Comment: I assumed so about the browser control but thank for clarifying. Assuming I go with 4 & 5, how do I handle 5 then? Do I upload one .xap (8.0) file first, then the other .xap (8.1) file? Do I name them differently? I assume this will be done in the "update", correct?

Comment: Upload xap and Windows Phone store will manage it for you. Screenshot of the one of [my apps in Windows Phone store](http://i.imgur.com/Vbe4Bcg.png).

Comment: Ok, I've changed all my files to links in my 8.0 project and will continue maintaining the 8.1 project going forward. Now I'm going try what you suggested. I'll update when I'm done.

Comment: Hi @crea7or, I've had numerous problems which I believe I have now fixed but it won't let me post due to the following error: The package identity associated with this update doesn't match what's in the uploaded package: "f7e821b9-c818-4517-87c7-9d5d1433ecaa". I can't see any "package id" in my wp8.0 project but this is available in the wp8.1 in the Package.appxmanifest. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use different project files for your projects? only sources should be shared ( .cs & .xaml ) and resources. [There is an article](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Maintaining_a_WP7_and_WP8_version_of_a_same_Silverlight_application) about sharing code between the projects.

Comment: No. I think they are the same because it was a copy of the entire project but .NET did something when it automatically upgraded me from 8 to 8.1 as I can see at least one new file i.e. package.appxmanifest but i'm not sure what else it did. I'm using my 8.1 as the main project and in my 8.0 project, I removed each file one at a time and replaced them with a link file instead. Should I create a new project and add link files to it or can I change the GUID? I'll go read the article and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, create new project and link files to the new project.

Comment: I'm having major problems here. Started from scratch and this time I kept my wp8 project as my main project and created a new wp8.1 project and started to add linked files. All is compiling without errors but when I try to run it in the emulator I get 'package could not be registered.'. Driving nuts!!! Anyway, I'll keep researching it tomorrow.